# Getting error "CreateStack failed: Size of the instance" when trying to launch g2.2xlarge on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm tryign to launch a g2.2xlarge instance on EC2 from N. Virginia (us-east-1).  I'm using an AMI which works on the older cg1.4xlarge GPU instance type.

At the final stage of the creating a stack wizard, I get the "CreateStack failed: Size of the instance" error message.  I can't find any documentation on this error message.

Any ideas why I'm seeing this?  My AMI is 25GB.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options:

- you don't have permissions (you weren't granted by root user of the AWS account)
- you reached limit to run large instances (check [How many instances can I run in Amazon EC2?](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#How_many_instances_can_I_run_in_Amazon_EC2).